# How to prevent @SpringBootScanApplications(scanbase="package") avoiding interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, maven

So I was running a Springboot application  then I got this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'sample.ArticledDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'sample.ArticledDao' in your configuration.
```

Then I checked how SpringBoot scans the files and I saw some of the files are ignored
[image: What component scan shows]

This is how the path looks ( It's not ideal I know) :

[image: path]

This is the code of my Main class :

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="sample")
@EnableJpaRepositories("sample")
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my ArticlesDao class:

```java
public interface ArticledDao {
    List<Articles> findAll();

    public void deleteArticles(Articles articles);
}
```

ArticleSercviceImp class

```java
@Component
public class ArticleSericeImp implements ArticlesServices
{
    @Autowired
    ArticledDao articleDao;
    @Override
    public List<Articles> findAll() {
        return articleDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Articles art) {
         articleDao.deleteArticles(art);
    }
```

ArticleRepository:

```
@Repository
public  class ArticlesRepository implements ArticledDao{


  public ArticlesRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Override
    public List<Articles> findAll() {
        return template.query("select * from article", new ArticlesRowMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteArticles(Articles articles) {
        final String sql = "delete from article where articleid=:articleid";
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("articleid", articles.getId());

        template.execute(sql,map,new PreparedStatementCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)
                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        });


    }



    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprinboot_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sprinboot_Project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm new to SpringBoot so I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you answering. Then  what do you think I should do fix the error so I could run my springboot app?

Comment: Do you have another class, that extends from ArticlesRepository? If not, then (i think) that class should not be abstract.

Comment: Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("sample")` to your `Main` class.

Comment: @dunni added now I'm dealing with the Parameter 0 of constructor in sample.ArticlesRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
error.

Comment: I update the code

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml? If you have the correct Spring Boot dependencies, AFAIK there should be an autoconfigured bean of that type, otherwise you would need to define it yourself.

Comment: I added at the bottom. @dunni Thank you for spending you time helping me to fix the issue. I really appreaciate it.

Comment: You seem to have all necessary dependencies, however a few things to improve: you have a duplicate `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` dependency, then instead of `spring-data-jpa` i would use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, and then you could also remove `hibernate-entitymanager`, because that would be added automatically as well by Data JPA. Otherwise i don't see any errors at the moment. Could you upload your project to Github, then i could have a closer look?

Comment: Sure here is the link : https://github.com/Editux/springboot

Comment: @dunni  Sorry to both you, but I wanted to ask have you checked the github? And if you have you spot anything unusual?

Comment: Ah sorry, i didn't get a notification for your earlier comment. I'll check it and get back to you.

Comment: I post my findings as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and removed the `spring-data` dependency as well (this will bring in all needed transitive dependencies like hibernate etc.).

Then you have excluded the datasource autoconfiguration in your application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

However this auto configuration is needed to autoconfigure the JdbcTemplate, which you use in your ArticleRepository class. So you need to remove that line. With those changes i can get at least to the point where it tries to connect to Postgres (which fails in my case because i don't have a running instance).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's definately worked thank you for checking my code. I will also upvote your other top posts as a thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that you're trying to inject the interface into some component, probably some service implementation that looks like this:

```
@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticeService {

   @Autowired
   private ArticleDao dao;
   ....
}

// or alternatively if you're using constructor injection: 

@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticeService {

  
   private final ArticleDao dao;
  
   public ArticleServiceImpl(ArticleDao dao) {
      this.dao = dao;
   }
}
```

In order to instantiate this service bean, spring needs to resolve its dependencies, which is, in this case, a single dependency of DAO expressed as an interface. So there has to be some real instance that implements that interface `ArticleDao`.

It seems like you haven't even created such a class, let alone you have to specify it as a bean as well. So spring merely can't find a proper match for injection, hence an error.

To solve this error you should have something like this:

```
@Repository
public class ArticleDaoImpl implements ArticleDao {
  // implement the methods of the interface
}
```

You might also be using spring data , but its a different story, I assume, the question is about the general spring injection principles...

Comment: @MarkBrammik I added the code of the classes to give you more insights.  I guess I did in both way .

Comment: Should I modify something?

Comment: Your class `ArticlesRepository` should not be abstract. Instances of abstract class cannot be created in Java. So remove the word `abstract`. Also you use `@Resource` annotation in the service. Remove it and use `@Autowired` instead

Comment: You mean using ```@Autowired``` in``` ArticleServiceImp``` class?

Comment: added now I'm dealing with the Parameter 0 of constructor in sample.ArticlesRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.

Comment: This is basically the same logic. If you want to inject a bean yiu should define one. As for ghe jdbc template you should read how to do that correctly in spring (data source, jdbc connection pooling etc)

Answer (score 0):

> A component required a bean of type 'sample.ArticledDao' that could not be found.

Spring IoC is trying to make sense of your Bean injections, but Spring cannot find a Bean of **type** matching `sample.ArticledDao`. Notice that in your code,

```java
@Repository
public  class ArticlesRepository implements ArticledDao
```

Based on your definition, the `ArticledDao` bean is not of the `ArticledDao` type, so it throws an error on

```
@Component
public class ArticleSericeImp implements ArticlesServices
{
    @Autowired
    ArticledDao articleDao;
// wrong.
```

In fact, the `ArticledDao` bean is of the `ArticlesRepository` type. Thus, in the consumers, you can autowire either

1.

```
@Component
public class ArticleSericeImp implements ArticlesServices
{
    @Autowired
    ArticledDao articlesRepository;
// ...
```

or,
2.

```
@Component
public class ArticleSericeImp implements ArticlesServices
{
    @Autowired
    ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;
// ...
```

Comment: So I should do autowire either of one in ```public class ArticlesRepository``` I've tried to doing both way but it's still throws me the same error.

Comment: @MayWheather Note that `ArticlesRepository` is the Bean provider and you consume (autowire) this `articlesRepository` Bean somewhere else in other places. I will update the answer soon to clarify this.